# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 8, size is 8

Tags: android

```
for(int j=0; j<ServiceProviderCal.ap_title_arr.size();j++)
{           
    if(ServiceProviderCal.ap_title_arr.get(position).isEmpty())
    {
         Holder.relative.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.rgb(255, 255,255));
    }
    else
    {
        Holder.txtNote1.setText(notes.get(position)+"  For:");
        Holder.txtNote2.setText(des.get(position));
        Holder.relative.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.rgb(255, 255,0));                 
        //Log.e("Notes...", ""+notes);  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This:

```
for(int j=0; j<=ServiceProviderCal.ap_title_arr.size();j++) {
```

should be:

```
for(int j=0; j<ServiceProviderCal.ap_title_arr.size();j++) {
```

Array indexes start from 0, so when you have an array of size 8, the maximum index in it is 7.

Comment: hey sorry..by mistake i remove the = sign...in my code i have already remove it but i am getting the error..so can u tell me other answer

Comment: OK, what the value of `position`?

Comment: i am adding the data in listview so position is the listview position..when user click any listview item the position value is getting and data is added in that position

Comment: Please edit your question and post at which line you get the exception and the stack trace from logcat.

Comment: if(ServiceProviderCal.ap_title_arr.get(position).isEmpty())   i am getting the error at that line..

Comment: seems like position is 8, which is out of bounds

Comment: I asked you to post the stacktrace and you didn't I have a limit of how much I can guess...

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are using

```
Holder.txtNote1.setText(notes.get(position)+"  For:");
        Holder.txtNote2.setText(des.get(position));
```

what is the **notes** and **des**. I am sure error comes from this code.

`notes` and `des` array list value should be equal to `ServiceProviderCal.ap_title_arr.size()`

So debug your code by logging the size of `notes` and `des` array.

Comment: notes and des is the array list..while i am adding the appointment notes is my title and des is my description.and its added in the listview..

Comment: I know notes and des is arraylist. you are using des.get(position) and position value is depends on ap_title_arr size. So des and notes array size also should be equal to ap_title_arr size.